# Binary strings such that the sum of 0's is not equal to twice the sum of 1's

Tags: context-free

Construct a context-free language for $L=\{w\in \{0,1\}^* \mid n_0(w)\not= 2n_1(w)\}$. Here $n_b(w)$ is the number of $b$'s in $w$.

I can construct a CFL in the case $n_0(w)=2n_1(w)$, but I have no idea how to construct it when they are not equal, considering that CFL is not closed under complement operation.

Answer (score 2):

Distinguish $n_0(w) < 2n_1(w)$ and $n_0(w) > 2n_1(w)$. That is, in your grammar for $n_0(w) = 2n_1(w)$ either generate extra $0$ or (in a separate half of the grammar) extra $1$.

Comment: Well, I wonder whether I can do it in the following way. Let $S$ represent strings $n_0(w)=2n_1(w)$, $A$ represent strings $n_0(w)>2n_1(w)$, $B$ represent strings $n_0(w)\ge 2n_1(w)$. Then we can have $A\rightarrow S0B$, $B\rightarrow S|A$.

Comment: Well, I just make it too complex. Thanks!